# I get a declaration error in solidity when I create a variable with "var"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create a variable "project" to store data from a mapping but I get "Decalration error, undefined identifier" on `project = projects[addr]`

````
function getProjectInfo(address addr) public view returns (string memory  name, string memory url, uint funds){
        var project = projects[addr];
        
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit variable type definition:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;


contract Test
{

    struct Project 
    {
        bytes32  name ;
    }

    mapping (address => Project) projects ;

    constructor  () public {
    }

   function getProjectInfo(address addr) public view returns (string memory  name, string memory url, uint funds)
   {
       Project memory project = projects[addr];
//   ...        
   }        
}
```